# breeding a male aggron with a ditto in a luxury ball yet still getting pokeball babies?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have a male aggron in an pokeball and a ditto in a luxury ball. i have tried breeding them but i get babies in an pokeball instead of the luxury ball. is there something im missing?

i also have Pokemon Y if that may be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Breeding Male - Ditto pokemon always results in Pokeball'd babies, regardless whether you have a different ball on the male or the Ditto.